# Domain .htaccess Redirect KEEPING LINKS

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I want to direct Domain1.com to Domain2.com

Naturally, you would add this to Domain1.com's HTACCESS file: 
    Redirect 301 / http://Domain2.com

However, there are many links posted on forums leading to files on Domain1. How can I keep those links in tact, while directing just the Domain1 index to Domain2? Is this possible with .htaccess?

---

edit: I know this is easy to do with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location = "http://domain2.com/"
//-->
</script>
```

I'm just trying to learn how .htaccess works.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I've put this in as Domain1's and it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I've cleared my cache too, any ideas? The TLD on domain 1 is international (.mw), the TLD on domain 2 is a .com. Don't know if that matters.

Comment: @user871614 did you modify the rewrite condition?

Comment: Yes sir. (Keeping the "\" separating the domain from the TLD present).